# Automatic consistency check of interface files

Tags: interface, static-libraries, fortran90

I would like to create a library in Fortran90, and figured that an okay way to do this was to collect the public routines in a file interface.f90 (with no modules), compile and collect everything into a ".a" static library, and maintain a file interface.inc with interface blocks corresponding to routines in interface.f90. 
I would then distribute the .a file together with interface.inc, so users can get type-checking at compile-time with "include 'interface.inc'".

The problem is that when developing the library, each time the interface of a public routine changes, the chance has to be manually made in two places: interface.f90, and interface.inc. 
The best case would be that interface.inc could be automatically generated from interface.f90 at the compilation of the library, but so far i've found no standardized way.

It would however be acceptable to manually change interface.inc, as long as any inconsistencies are caught when compiling the library. 
So what i'm asking is: Is there any way to automatically check the consistency (when compiling the library) of the interface blocks in interface.inc with the actual routines found in interface.f90?

Comment: I'd try to extract your interface.inc from the module via some scripting language. If you follow some simple convention, like subroutine name is followed immediately by local variables followed by an empty line or so, it should not be too complicated. I did once something similar, however, for Fortran 77-type interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a language sense in Fortran 90.  It is possible that a particular processor might offer this as a diagnostic capability, but they are not required to.

In terms of automatic interface generation - one processor that I am aware of (Intel Fortran) with suitable command line options will write out interface blocks for each external procedure that it encounters.  It uses this for interface checking of external procedures.  I have seen some users harvest these interface blocks for similar reasons to your own.  This is relying on a very processor specific behaviour though, and changes in that behaviour from time to time occasionally break this arrangement.

In Fortran 2003 the possibility for consistency checking *may* exist.  The approach is in a separate module declare procedure pointers based off the interface blocks.  Then, inside each actual procedure, use the module with the procedure pointers and (perhaps inside an debugging if construct or similar) attempt to associate that relevant procedure pointer with the actual procedure.  Compilers are not required to diagnose mismatch in procedure pointer explicit interfaces, but most should.  See posts towards the end of [this forum thread](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/355850) for some discussion (note there's an error in the F2008 standard that formally "fails to provide an interpretation" for the procedure pointer assignment, but I think that will be corrected in corrigendum two).

In terms of packaging your interface blocks to end users, consider putting them in a module and providing the source for that module.  This will give you far more flexibility in what you can provide to your users in future.

```
MODULE interfaces
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE
  PUBLIC :: external
  INTERFACE
    SUBROUTINE external(arg)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: arg(:)
    END SUBROUTINE external
  END INTERFACE
END MODULE interfaces

MODULE proc_pointers
  USE interfaces
  IMPLICIT NONE
  PRIVATE
  LOGICAL, PARAMETER, PUBLIC :: check_flag = .TRUE.
  PROCEDURE(external), POINTER, PUBLIC :: external_pptr
END MODULE proc_pointers

SUBROUTINE external(arg)
  USE proc_pointers
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: arg(:)
  IF (check_flag) external_pptr => external
  ...    
END SUBROUTINE external
```